# What does return True/False actually do? (Python)

Tags: python, function, if-statement, return

I've added in a sample code below just so you have a frame of reference for what my question actually is. I always see programs with if statements that return True or False, but what is actually happening here, why wouldn't you just want to put a print statement for false/true. I'm lost here.

```
def false(x,y):
    x > y
    return False

false(9,10)
```

Comment: `return True` handles _errors_ whereas `return False` it does not!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because most of the time you'll want to do something with the result other than print it. By using a return value, the function does one thing: do the calculation, and the caller can do whatever it wants with it: print it, write it to a database, use it as part of some larger calculation, whatever. The idea is called [composability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composability).

Also your example doesn't currently make much sense as it will always return `False` after evaluating `x > y` but doing nothing with the result. Perhaps you meant something like:

```
def is_greater(x, y):
    if x > y:
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

Then `is_greater` is something that can easily be used in whatever context you want. You could do:

```
x = is_greater(a, b)
write_to_super_secret_database(x)
```

(In real life you probably wouldn't use a function to do something so trivial, but hopefully the example makes sense.)

Comment: Would you mind sharing an example with me of how this would be useful?

Comment: I just don't understand where it's being returned too? Why shouldn't you just replace return with print in this instance. I guess I just want to know what can the True/False be used for? When you run the program nothing happens even when you call the function. Why would you want to return True/False.

Comment: A bit more.. how about now?

Comment: Yeah I think so, so It's storing the result in x. if you printed x it would equal true/false?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Precisely. (This comment brought to you by the 15-character minimum in comments :P )

Answer (score 5):

Functions which return True / False are used in further statements like IF:

Like this:

```
def is_bigger(x,y):
  return x > y

if is_bigger(10,9):
  do_something
elif:
  print "math don't work anymore"
```

you should take a look at variables and control structures:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Comment: I understand how this works, I'm what is the point of putting return False/True at the end of a function when you could just create a print statement within an if statment. Where is that True/False being returned too?

Comment: @HawkeyeNate Your function does nothing with x,y at all - the comparison is discarded and false is always returned. "Return" means "return to parent" whereas print simply prints to the output - you cannot do anything with a printed value, whereas a returned value might be stored in a variable